# Convert text to a formatted number type

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am helping someone tidy up a database. It is indexed by an ID of the text type in form A-BBB, where A and B are digits 0-9. This form is desired for our application, the only drawback that it is sorted by ASCII standards, so numbering goes 1, 10, 2 etc. Obviously, we would like it to sort by A, then sort by BBB. So IDs 1-001, 10-010, 1-010 and 10-001 would be sorted 1-001, 1-010, 10-001 and 10-010.

I have tried to change the table to save number types, and use a number of format `#\###` to allow for the '-' character. From what I understand about formatted numbers, the # stores a digit and \ shows the next character as a literally looks.

Am I completely off track in solving this problem or is there something small that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by each half, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
ORDER BY Val(Left(ID,Instr(Id,"-"))), Val(Mid(ID,Instr(Id,"-")+1))
```

Comment: +1 This is the appeoach I would have taken, my Order By line looked like this though: "ORDER BY CDbl(Mid([ID],1,InStr([ID],"-")-1)), CDbl(Right([ID],Len([ID])-InStr([ID],"-")))"